# Catch urls containing certain character in routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes, url-routing

I have three rules in `routes.rb`:

```
match ":topic", to: 'topics#show', via: :get, as: :topic    

match ":topic/:multi_city(/:year(/:month))", to: "multi_cities#show", via: :get, as: :multi, constraints: {multi_city: /.*\+.*/}

scope ":topic" do
  scope ":city" do
    match "organizers", to: 'organizers#index', via: :get, as: :topic_organizers
    match "(:year(/:month))", to: "communities#show",   via: :get, as: :community
  end
end
```

The intention is to cover the following three cases, in order:

```
/football/  # only the topic  
/football/chicago+seattle+portland/  # a topic and a combination of cities  
/football/chicago # a topic and a single city
```

The rules work by themselves, but the problem is that they interfer with eachother.

Currently the first rule doesn't get applied as the second one is catching those requests, despite me trying to constrain the second one to only catch urls with a secondary part that contains the `+` sign.

**How can I construct the second rule such that it ONLY catches requests that contain URLs with two segments (and the second segment has to contain a plus sign)?**

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to ensure you have one city, then a splat of more:

```
get ":topic/:city+:multi_cities" => "controller#action", :multi_cities => /\w[\+]?[\w]?/
```

You could then parse `params[:multi_cities]` in your controller to break the cities apart even further.

Comment: The first option, isn't that what I have already? `constraints: {multi_city: /.*\+.*/}`

Comment: Ah yes, I missed that - my bad.